# PyGame Zero - Reloading image from a folder

Tags: python, pgzero

I am wanting to 'reload' an image in PyGame Zero. This image will be updated outside of the game - so when the image is updated I'd like the new image (same file name) to be shown on the screen.

How can I achieve this?

```
WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500

drone = Actor('drone')

def draw():
    screen.clear()  
    drone.draw()

def update():
    drone = Actor('drone')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt), if you want to change a variable in global namespace within a function:

```py
def update():
    global drone
    drone = Actor('drone')
```